# Combine loops (foreach) in php into one to reduce server load

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

Im having to loops through multiple tables but its slowing my page load down by a fair amount. I currently have:

```
foreach($player as $play){
...
}
foreach($owns as $own){
...
}
foreach($discover as $discovere){
...
}
foreach($stronghold as $strongholds){
...
}
foreach($enemies as $enemy){
...
}
foreach($nodes as $node){
...
}
foreach($clans as $clan){
...
}
```

these all run on one page in the order above. Is there any way to combine these to take some of the strain off the server?

Comment: Given the information in the question, I can't imagine how they can be combined.  Each one does entirely different things with entirely different data.

Comment: you can combine them if all the crucial arrays have same number of elements

Comment: We need a lot more info to help. But a broad suggestion would be to investigate what data has to be live, and what can be cached.

Comment: Each loop is for an array which is each retrieved from a different database. The data is used to populate the page, once its been populated the page wont change until it's refreshed. I didn't know if there wa a less resource hungry method as the page takes in the region of 6 seconds to load compared to <1 on most others i have.

Comment: as you explained that each array have data retrieved from a different database. the question does the data model for all this collections are the same or they are a different in data model

Comment: @Mystic: How have you confirmed that these loops are the bottleneck for the page load?  If you're querying *7 different databases* when the page loads, that would seem *far* more likely to be the bottleneck.

Comment: Need to think about how much data you are fetching on the DB, can you reduce de dataset? Is everything indexed? can you optimize you query?
Maybe, do more queries but with faster query and smaller result set?? WE would need to know how much data you are looping, million of records? What are the loop for.... ICan you feed us more code so we can have a better idea what the 'LOAD' is all about?